# Google datastore lock timeout

Tags: google-app-engine, transactions, google-cloud-datastore

I was wondering what happens if I run a transaction inside of Google Datastore and something happens along the way where I can't finish the transaction (say application server dies while waiting for response). At this point the transaction would be locking the entity. How could I be cleanly unlock the entity without deleting/restarting/etc? Is there a timeout of any sort (say if the transaction takes longer than 10 seconds to fail it)?

Comment: Transactions don't lock entities. The datastore transactions are based on optimistic concurrency control: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimistic_concurrency_control

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [Google Cloud Datastore documentation](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/transactions), `Transactions have a maximum duration of 60 seconds with a 10 second idle expiration time after 30 seconds`. So they will time themselves out.

If the server dies and you get a transaction timeout, you will get back an exception. If your application dies, then the transaction should just timeout and, since transactions are atomic, will not retain the broken data.

So there shouldn't be any need to clean up, other than to just resend the data if you get an exception from the datastore.

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help!

Comment: Also, if you need to handle server errors gracefully, here's some [nice documentation on that too.](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/handling_datastore_errors)

Comment: afaik theres no need for the expiration part. datastore transactions do not lock entities.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, transactions do expire. As it happens, just today I had a programming "oops" which resulted in a transaction not completing properly -- and thus I got a 500 HTTP status and, in the logs, a log, detailed traceback ending in

```
BadRequestError: The referenced transaction has expired or is no longer valid
```

Peculiarly, when I ran the very same code again (trying to understand exactly what I was doing wrong), the second time the HTTP 500 was accompanied by a traceback ending in

```
DeadlineExceededError: The overall deadline for responding to the HTTP request was exceeded.
```

Same underlying error in my code (I was taking too long to respond), two different exceptions -- i.e some "race condition" about which error would trigger first, since deadlines for both problems are equal, 60 seconds.

BTW, this is all w/Python (always my favorite:-) but while names etc can change, the underlying logic of the datastore should be the same in any GAE supported language.